# Moving extrusions on bent surface

Tags: cad, autodesk-inventor

Hi there I found my self with a broken pair of headphones for which I am designing a spare part in Inventor right now. (Using Inventor Professional 2020).

I have the problem that I have a set of extrusions to move since they are interfering with other parts of the model and because the model itself is not in the right dimensions yet (I went with modelling the part to coarsely resemble the proportions and shape and bother with the dimensions last which is usually a straightforward enough thing to do). Now how can I move the extrusions shown in the below picture? I have tried moving the axis on which I have placed the extrusions but that leaves me with the end of the extrusion hanging in the air which is obviously not to be desired. Moving the layer on which the 2D Shape to be extruded is drawn after moving the axis is not possible since this results in an infinite loop of dependencies (why actually?) 
[image: extrusions to move]
[image: air gap when moved]
[image: error message when redefining the 2d draft layer]

Since I just realized that other than in some other SE(-ish) sites it is not posible to post attachments you find the 3D model of my part here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Kg2T7q0JwWIVn6-k4mO3M5ZtNvWAFk4N
so you can tinker around with it as needed. If someone sports an older version of Inventor I can provide a version saved in an older format on demand.

Obviously answers like "remodel it completely" are not the type of advice I want to hear. If it is really not possible without going beyond reasonable labour ok then be it that way else not.

EDIT: As pointed out by Optical Resonator it is not clear that I tried to go with an extrusion that is always orthogonal on the bent surface but this is what I tried to archive...

Comment: Bad luck - I uninstalled Inventor 2 days ago, so can't poke around in your file... As I understand it, you want to move the extrusion away, changing the distance of its centre from 5 to 6mm from the RH edge. So, you need to make a reference sketch on the XY plane containing a point that's 6mm from the edge, then define a reference plane which is tangent to the curved face, and perpendicular to the XY Plane, and passes through that point. Put your extrude sketches on this plane, and then extrude up to the next body.

Comment: And, "remodel it completely" may not be the type of advice that you want to hear, but that doesn't stop it from being *objectively good advice*. You can learn a huge amount from this process - it's always much faster the second time around, and you can often restructure your model to be much more robust, and to avoid dependency loops, by rebuilding things strictly in dependency order, once you have the full picture in mind.

Comment: the change from 5 to 6 mm is just for illustrational purposes i have not yet measured the real dimension i need to put in. also the process you have mentioned while not exactly resembling what i did is somewhat close. having the full picture in mind is something that is literally a joke to me since i have the original part that is broken and need to be replaced in front of me on my desk. I dont have to get a picture in the mind.

Comment: I meant a clear picture in terms of how to model it - how the sketches are defined etc. Not the original model. Eg those extrudes might have been revolves